# Is Draupadi a goddess?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, pandavas, draupadi

There are many myths that say Draupadi is a goddess. Many people, including myself, have prayed to her. There are many legends of her being a goddess. Some legends are given below:

- It is said that Draupadi is incarnation of wives of Dharma, Vayu, Indra and Aswini Kumaras. The wives of Dharma, Vayu, Indra and Aswini Kumaras are however stepmothers to the Pandavas. In that case how did they marry her?
- Draupadi is said to be Kali, the wife of Shiva. How did she, then, marry not one but five Pandavas instead of an avatar of Shiva?

Comment: Draupadi is **"SRI"** not Lord Vishnu's wife but amalgamation of wives of Indra, Dharma, Vayu and Aswini Kumaras. She was called as **SRI** due to opulence. She might be an aspect of Shakti (amalgamation of five Shaktis: wives of aforementioned Devas ) but not complete Shakti (**KAALI**). Pandavas should also be considered as Devas if Draupadi is goddess.

Comment: @AnilKumar Well, at least that's what Madhvacharya says in his Mahabharata Tatpara Nirnaya, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6682/36 But I'm not entirely convinced that he's right.  I think it's possible that it could be Vishnu's wife Lakshmi; the Mahabharata specifically says that this "Sri" figure asked permission from Vishnu to be born as the wife of the Pandavas, so that suggests that it may be Vishnu's wife.  Of course, the counterargument is that Lakshmi would never be the wife of anyone other than Vishnu.

Comment: @ Keshav Srinivasan "The Pandavas were all SONS of gods: Yudhishthira was the son of Yama god of death, Bhima was the son of Vayu the wind god, Arjuna was the son of Indra king of the gods, and Nakula and Sahadeva were sons of the twin Ashwini Kumaras. But these weren't the only gods they were INCARNATIONS of."I got this from the above link.How can the Pandavas be INCARNATIONS of the devas 8f they were their SONS?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan According to Shaivites, Siva is Supreme purusha and "Shakti" is supreme Prakriti or female energy. Similarly according to Vaishnavites, Vishnu is Supreme Purusha, His Shakti or Sri woould be supreme "Shakri". According to me, names only change in Puranas. What does Viashnava puranas say about Primordial Shakti? Is she Mahalakshmi, like Adi Shakti in Shaiva perspective?

Comment: @KVickneshvara Sometimes **SONS are considered as Avatars**. Shiva's seed was taken by Vayu and He was born as Hanuman to Anjani. Anjani was just Vanara and Hanuman may be thus called as Avatar of Shiva. But Shiva's seed (**URJA**) with Prakriti transformed to **KAARTIKEYA**, who is son and God but not Avatar of Shiva. Same is the case with Ayyappa. This is my understanding and i'm not sure whether this is correct or not. i think Kunti was normal human being and so sons of those Devas can be considered as Avatars of those 5 Devas.

Comment: @KVickneshvara You can ask that as separate question. See this related question  [Soul (Atma) of Arjuna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8705/3500)

Comment: Can any of you write about Draupadi as Kali?

Comment: One clarification here.. Draupadi is mentioned as **celestial Sri** (that means Shachi and not Goddess Lakshmi) http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Draupadi is a goddess **celestial Sri** (not Goddess Lakshmi but Shachi/Sachi).

In [Adi Parva-> Sambhava Parva of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm):

> The faultless Draupadi, slender-waisted like the wasp, was born of a portion of **Sachi** (the queen of the celestials), in the line of Drupada.

[image]

In [Adi Parva->Vaivahika Parva of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm), Vyasa says:

> O king, they who have been born as the Pandavas are none else than those Indras of old. And the **celestial Sri** herself who had been appointed as their wife is this Draupadi of extraordinary beauty.

[image]

The same is confirmed by Indra himself in [Svargarohanika Parva of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18004.htm).

The same is confirmed in [Markandeya purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/markandeya-purana/chapter-05/topic-1):

> The adorable Indra became incarnate in five forms (5 Pandavas). His wife was born as Draupadi from Agni: she is the wife of Indra alone, and of no one else.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Than who is Subhadra, another wife of Arjuna and sister of Krishna?

Answer (score 0):

•Draupadi is said to be Kali, the wife of Shiva. How did she, then, marry not one but five Pandavas instead of an avatar of Shiva?
Answer --- All Five Pandavas were Avatars of Shiva. They were Rudras and yes all Pandavas have been Indras also Yudhister has been Indra many many times.

Comment: Do add some [references and citations to confirm the accuracy of your answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/793/4459). Note that we have a strict [Back it up!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/4459) rule on this site. Do go through the [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/4459). Good luck!

Comment: Draupadi and Subhadra were sisters of Krishna and corresponding to Kali and BhadraKali

Comment: Shiva is 5 Bhoot Naath himself (Akash/Yudhistra, Vayu/Bhima, Agni/Arjun, Jaal/Nakul and Prithvi/Sehdeva) or 5 Pandavas. Har Har Mahadeva

Comment: @user16546 Hey, Drupadi is the daughter of Drupada But, Subhadra was the daughter of Vasudeva (Lord Krishna's father). How did Drupadi become the sister of Krishna?