# Why is Sita worshiped well but not Draupadi?

Tags: mahabharata, worship, sita, draupadi

Let us consider the [following](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18004.htm) excerpt from Mahabharata

> "He also beheld the princess of Pancala, decked in garlands of lotuses. Having attained to Heaven, she was sitting there, endued with a form possessed of solar splendour. King Yudhishthira suddenly wished to question her. **Then the illustrious Indra, the chief of the gods, spoke to him, ‘This one is Sree herself. It was for your sake that she took birth, as the daughter of Drupada, among human beings, issuing not from any mother’s womb, O Yudhishthira**, endued with agreeable perfume and capable of delighting the whole world. For your pleasure, she was created by the wielder of the trident. She was born in the race of Drupada and was enjoyed by you all. These five highly blessed Gandharvas endued with the effulgence of fire, and possessed of great energy, were, O king, the sons of Draupadi and yourself.

From that, it is clear that the Draupadi is Laskhmi itself in Dvapara like Sita in Treta yuga. Sita is well worshipped and Draupadi is hardly worshipped. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Each yuga has its Shakti. In treta, Shakti was Sita. In Dwapara, she was Radha. It is natural for the Superior shakti to be worshipped over the minor one(s). Draupadi is swarga lakshmi only. Not Mahalakshmi of Vaikuntha.  Rukmini was born with the original Lakshmi aspect. Your premise is incorrect.

Comment: Found this "The Tamil community celebrates the Thimithi Festival to worship Draupadi" - https://www.makemytrip.com/blog/thimithi-festival-when-draupadi-is-worshipped

Comment: Thing again whom you are comparing! Supreme Goddess Lakshmi is unmatchable and uncomparable. And Dropadi was not incarnation of Lakshmi (Wife of Narayana).

Comment: @Rishabh Sita has prominent role in the destruction of daemons and the same Draupadi has. The contribution of Draupadi in  dharma sanstapana is more than any other shakti incarnations at that time.

Comment: And how is that? What Draupadi did for Dharma which made Draupadi superior than all?

Comment: @Rishabh Sita was kidnapped by Ravana and she faced so many difficulties, leads to the destruction of  Ravana. Similarly In Dvapara yuga Draupadi got insult and faced so many difficulties and triggered pandavas to take action aganist Duryodhana, keechaka and others.

Comment: You are wrong my friend. Mahabharat war was not fought to get revenge of draupadi. There is no way that big war will be held to get justice of single person. It was fought to ends the cruality of korwas. It was cleared by Yudhishtir and Lord Krishna himself that war was not held coz of only Draupadi.

Comment: True, I am not saying that she was the only the reason for war. But she was the only Shakti suffered a lot due to the  cruel nature of Kauravas and she was the only shati who asked pandavas (with pain) to take proper action against many deamons. Is it false?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61752/discussion-between-hanugm-and-rishabh).

Comment: This is a good question itself (Why Mahabharat was was fought). If it is not being asked till now here then you can ask. There you will get to know about the real reason of war. And draupadi was great but not greatest. There were other great saint lady also there like Kunti and Gandhari whose sacrifices was even greater than Draupadi's.

Comment: Draupadi is widely worshipped as a form of Kali by Tamils around the world, like India, Fiji and Singapore

Comment: @hanugm "From that, it is clear that the Draupadi is Laskhmi itself in Dvapara like Sita in Treta yuga" -- NO, Draupadi is mentioned as celestial Sri (that means Shachi and not Goddess Lakshmi) sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01200.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Draupadi a goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/is-draupadi-a-goddess)

Comment: Isn't Draupadi worshiped as a goddess in Tamil Nadu? I might be wrong, but I think there are temples dedicated to her were devotees walk on fire.

Answer (score 4):

**Sita worshiped well but not Draupadi** is due to the following reason

> A goddess can be worshiped if her husband himself a God(incarnation of one of Trimurthi).

Goddess Sita was an avatar of Lakshmi and her husband is Rama, who was an avatar of Vishnu. Rama can be worshiped and hence Sita.

[Radha](http://nitaaiveda.com/Compiled_and_Imp_Scriptures/Glories_of_Shri_Radha/Meeting_of_Radha_Krishna/Marriage_of_Radha_Krishna.htm), Rukmini can be worshiped because they are wives of Krishna and are also forms of Shakti.

Draupadi was a form of sree Shakti, but her husbands are not ansa of Trimurthi. Hence Draupadi is not worshipped.

> **There exists no goddess worshiped without her husband worshiped.**

Comment: Does your thumb rule has any valid references?

Comment: It's wrong. Dhumavati is a widow, still worshipped. She is infact one of the *Dasam-MAhAvidyAs*

Answer (score 3):

Mother Sita is a form of Lakshmi Devi. However, Mother Draupadi is a form of Sachi Devi. Please see the reference from Sripada Srivallabha Charitamrutam below (Page 87 of the English version):

***The cursed Devendra was born as five ‘Pandavas’. Though there were five forms and five
minds, the atma which was the support of them all was one. This was a strange thing. Sachi Devi manifested in the yajna kundam as Draupadi. She was an ‘Ayonija’.***

Answer (score 1):

Let's see some genuine scriptures on what they say about chitrakut biharni maa Sita

**आद्या सा प्रकृति सीता आद्यस्तु पुरुषोत्तम।
गुणातीतो भवान्नित्यो नित्यभुता सनातनी।।**

That first nature (आदि प्रकृति) is Sita and the first is the best of men.( श्रीराम ही आदि पुरुषोत्तम हैं). Transcendental to the modes of nature, Thou art eternal, ever-being, eternal.

Maha sundari tantra

**जानक्यांश आदि संभुतानेक ब्रह्माण्डकारिणी।
सा मुलप्रकृतिर् ज्ञेयो महामाया स्वरुपिणी।।**

All shaktis (uma, laxmi, saraswati and other devis) have originated from Maa Sita’s ansh kala and she playfully creates infinte universes. Sarveshwari adijagadamba maa Sita is adidevi of all shaktis and hence called as mool prakruti and is independent ruler of all

~maha ramayan

**अस्या कटाक्षमात्रेण कोटिब्रह्माण्ड निर्मितः। कोटयः विरचीनं विष्णुनां चैव कोटयः।
कोटयश्च रुद्रानां शक्राणां चैव कोटयः। उत्पद्यन्ते विकुर्वन्ति विलीयन्ते ततस्तथा।।**

Aadi Ramayan 3.66.2&3

From only eyelashes of maa sita, crores of universes are created with crores of brahma, vishnu,Mahesh, Indra and other devas. By her power alone, all of the universes are created and destroyed.

Comment: Sir OP is asking about the reason why Devi Draupadi is not worshipped like Devi Sita if she's also a form of Sri devi.

Comment: Crores of universes from Sita’s eyelashes, what a wonderful imagery  I like that a lot 

Comment: Its also written in narad pancharatra antargat Anand samhita, brihadbrahma samhita, vasisht samhita, maha ramayan, lomesh samhita and many other ramayan eg agastya ramayan, lomesh ramayan etc.  But people haven't read those,

Comment: Draupadi is incarnation of some Devi as i remember and she cannot be compared to maa Sita (the supre goddess of goddesses like uma, laxmi , saraswati and other devis)