# Are there any instances where god and his consort incarnated as siblings in Vaivasvata-manvantara?

Tags: avatars, marriage

**SB 4.1** states that Lord Vishnu and Goddess Laxmi incarnated as siblings Yajña and Dakṣiṇā. They were actually children of Ruchi and Akuti. But, Svāyambhuva Manu brought home Yajña, and Ruci, his son-in-law kept Dakṣiṇā. Yajña and Dakṣiṇā later got married.

The above incident is from Svāyambhuva-manvantara, the beginning of creation. Are there any instances where god and his consort incarnated as siblings in Vaivasvata-manvantara? If yes, whom they got married?

Comment: Draupadi was incarnation of Sri. And Krishna, of Vishnu. Krishna and Draupadi are not direct siblings, but "sibling-like", since Arjuna was Krishna's brother-in-law, thru Subhadra, who was Krishna's sister.

Comment: Draupadi was not an incarnation of Laxmi..she was an incarnation of [celestial Sri i.e. Sachi (Indra's wife)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22826/12304).. @LazyLubber

Comment: Could not find the verse in BORI edition. https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh01.itx

Comment: The linked post has Sanskrit verse as well from 3 places of Mahabaharata and Markandeya Purana..

Comment: I could not find the first reference in BORI, as I mentioned earlier. The second reference in that link is actually saying that Draupadi is Lakshmi. How Lakshmi became Sachi, I have no idea. For the third reference, it would be helpful if you can give the sanskrit verse from svargarohanika parva. As for the purANa, I would probably ignore it, if the Mbh says diffetently.

Comment: Ok, I checked the third link to sacred texts in English. Here is what I found: (Then the illustrious Indra, the chief of the gods, spoke to him, ‘**This one is Sree herself.** It was for your sake that she took birth, as the daughter of Drupada, among human beings, issuing not from any mother’s womb, O Yudhishthira, endued with agreeable perfume and capable of delighting the whole world. For your pleasure, she was created by the wielder of the trident. She was born in the race of Drupada and was enjoyed by you all). I could not find any reference to Sachi here.

Comment: @LazyLubber You left few line before this text, if you analyse you ll find that it talks about celestial Sree (Sree of Swarga/heaven) and not Laxmi..Anyway, what's the context of such things on this post? I will update that answer once i get sometime..bdw by siblings i meant born to same parents (atleast mother or father should be same)..