# How come Yajña married His own sister Dakṣiṇā?

Tags: vishnu, bhagavata-purana, marriage, lakshmi, manu

In [this](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/1/) canto of the Shrimad Bhagavatam
Yajña Who is identified as Hari married His uterine sister Dakṣiṇā Who's identified as the partial avatāra of Lakshmi.

So They had the **same** gotra

Even if the boy's gotra changed with Manu adopting him they were still born of the **same** mother's pinda(womb).

How come the marriage is valid, then?

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37114/12304

Comment: actually in the beginning there was no such restriction..Brahma's manasputras married their brother (daksha's) daughters and other such instances..

Comment: @YDS Dhanyavaad

Comment: Then everything in the universe belong to God yo Naha pitha janitha mantra of rig veda says he is father of creation he is father to Lakshmi matha also so human rules shall not be applied directly to God's