# How could Pandavas marry Draupadi, who is their stepmother's rebirth?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

I got a doubt from this question: [Who were the previous Indras that incarnated as the Pandavas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6682/2995)

> The Pandavas were all SONS of gods: Yudhishthira was the son of Yama god of death, Bhima was the son of Vayu the wind god, Arjuna was the son of Indra king of the gods, and Nakula and Sahadeva were sons of the twin Ashwini Kumaras. But these weren't the only gods they were INCARNATIONS of.

Given that, how can the Pandavas be incarnations of the Devas themselves when they were in fact their **sons**?

Also, it is said that Draupadi is incarnation of wives of Dharma, Vayu, Indra and Aswini Kumaras. The wives of Dharma, Vayu, Indra and Aswini Kumaras are however stepmothers to the Pandavas (who are the sons of the Devas). **In that case how could they marry their stepmothers' incarnation?**

I am not asking about Draupadi's swayamvara (i.e., how she got married), but about her as well as Pandavas' incarnations. Please clear my doubts.

Comment: Pandavas are a collective incarnation of indra and Draupadi is an incarnation of swarga lakshmi. Therefore it is sanctioned.

Comment: @moonstar2001  How can the Pandavas be INCARNATIONS of the devas(or Indra in your case) if they were their SONS?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Also do you have any sources?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did all the Pandavas marry Draupadi?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/231/why-did-all-the-pandavas-marry-draupadi)

Comment: Hanuman is said to be born from seed of Shiva (Son of Shiva) to a vanara female. Hanuman is avatar of Rudra. Avatars have energies of original purusha. Krishna is 100% incarnation of Vishnu. Rama is 80% and Parasurama is ansh avatar. Hanuman has some energy or soul of Rudra. But Kartikeya has both souls or energies of Shiva and Adi Shakti. That's the reason we don't call Kartikeya as Avatar of Shiva.

Comment: You are thinking of Physical bodies. Just think of Atma which is eternal. Arjuna has soul of Nara and Indra. So, he has only soul of Indra not his wife soul, so he is partial incarnation of Indra. Same is the case with other Pandavas.

Comment: @Anil Kumar Firstly who said that Krishna,Rama and Parasurama  are not equal in power.There ***is*** a reason why why all of them are part of the Dashavatar. Also, as asked in the question, how can the Pandavas be INCARNATIONS of the devas(or Indra in your case) if they were their SONS?

Comment: @Amil Kumar Also do you have any sources?

Comment: @KVickneshvara Don't you read my reply properly. What do you mean by power? Obviously Krishna is more divine than other two avatars.

Comment: @AnilKumar Okay but then why do people mostly refer to them as sons and not avtars?

Comment: @KVickneshvara I think those who have little knowledge on Hinduism may tend to say as sons but people with knowledge of our scriptures say them as both sons and Avatars.

Comment: @AnilKumar Thanks for clearing my doubt but i have one last teensy qestion...U said that if two souls merged they only formed a son.You also said that hanuman was born from Shiva's seed hence he grew in anjana's womb.thus,how is he an avaatr?

Comment: @KVickneshvara Hanuman has only powers or soul of Rudra. Anjana was just Vanara and has no power. But for Skanda, he has two energies of Shiva and Shakti. See [Soul (Atma) of Arjuna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8705/3500). Hence, we call Hanuman as Avatar of Shiva and Kartikeya as son of Shiva and Shakti.

Comment: @So they are son if only divine+divine right?

Comment: also does this have any scriptual basis

Comment: @KVickneshvara This is my understanding and i think it's correct. Don't compare son and Avatar. In case of Ganesha, initially Parvati made a boy with her energy but when Shiva beheaded boy with Trisul. His male energy transformed into Vinayaka and now Ganesha became true son Shiva and Shakti. Harihara was born from both energies of Shiva and Vishnu but He is not Avataar of Vishnu or Shiva but rather called as son of both. See that question i linked.

Comment: @AnilKumar which question?

Comment: @KVickneshvara [Soul (Atma) of Arjuna](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8705/3500)

Comment: Erm... I have a theory why the Pandavas married their own stepmothers' incarnation.When Kunti called the Devas,the Devas **incarnated as their own sons**.Does this make sense?

Comment: @KVickneshvara In incarnations, prior relationships do not matter - otherwise Krishna could not have married 16108 women because some of them were **rishis** in their previous birth, some of them were other women, some of them were the **wives of the devas**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Markandeya Purana there is [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/markandeyapurana4.html) chapter where Rishi Jaimini asks the same question to the Holy Birds viz-"How could Draupadi marry the Pancha Pandavas?."

Quoting from the above link:

> Apprehending the severe penance of Trishira, the son of powerful
>   Brahmana Twashta, Indra suspected danger of his own position and thus
>   killed Trishira. Twashta went into a rage and plucked a strand of hair
>   from his head and offered it in the homa kunda (Fire Pit) by his
>   mantrik power and created the mighty Vritrasura whose mission was to
>   kill Indra, who had already lost his sheen since he committed a
>   Brahmana. Indra deputed the Sapta Rishis to strike a deal with Vritra
>   so that he would not put Indra to immediate danger; but Vritra was
>   killed unawares by Indra.
>
> These actions angered the community of Rakshasas resulting in
>   continuous warfare against Devas and Prithvi felt great burden of the
>   atrocities by the demons. Prithvi appealed to Indra and the Deities
>   who in turn took the forms of Pandavas.
>
> Yadindradeham cha Tejasthanmumocha Swayam Vrishah, Kunthyamjaatho
>   Mahatejaastatho Raja Yudhishtarah/ Balam mumocha Pavanastatho Bhimo
>   vyajaayat, Shakraveeryardhatas chaiva jajney Paarthom Dhananjayah/
>   Utpanno Yamalou Maadriyam Shaka Rupou Mahadyuti, Panchadhaa
>   Bhagavannityamavateernah Shatukratuh/ Tasyotpanna Mahabhaaga Patni
>   KrishnaHutaashanat, Shakrasyaikasya sa Patni Krishna naanyascha
>   kasyachit/ Yogeeswaraah shareeraani Kurvati bahulaanyapi,
>   Panchaanaameka Patnitwamityetatkathitham tav
>
> Meaning-Dharmaraja himself from the body  of Indra deposited his
>   virility into Kunti from which was created Yudhishtara. The Deity of
>   Wind viz. Pavan deposited Indra’s radiance into Kunti as a result of
>   which Bhima was born. Indra gave away half of his ‘Shakti’ to Kunti
>   and Dhananjaya was thus born. Indra’s virility was transferred through
>   the two Ashwani Kumars to Devi Maadri and was born the pair of Nakul
>   and Sahadeva. **Indra’s ‘Amshas’ (alternatives) were manifested among
>   all the five Pandava brothers clearly. Moreover, Indra’s wife Shachi
>   Devi as Yagnaseni was created from ‘Agni’ and hence Draupadi was
>   Indra’s own better half.Yogeswar Purush Indra could divide his own
>   radiance into as many parts as per his volition.**
>
> Hence, it was amply justified that Draupadi was indeed the common wife
>   of the five Pandavas.

The portion in bold in the above quote is the justification you're looking for.

If you want to know about the Holy Birds and how they came into existence then read [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/markandeyapurana2.html) chapter of the same Purana.

Comment: So Yama, Vayu, and the Ashwini twins' sons were incarnations of Indra and Indra's son was an incarnation of Indra too?

Comment: Nice answer mate

Comment: Thanks buddy.. this was posted by me two years back..your comment reminded me of this answer :D @Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: Haha well its good to keep refreshing the memory :)